# Attribute th:each is not allowed here(Error in Thymeleaf template)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have created the application that stores the Information about dogs in the database,while running the project the tables where created but dogs information were not updates.

There is an error in running this below html file

The following code is not working

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- META SECTION -->
    <title>Dog Rescue</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <!-- END META SECTION -->
    <!--  BEGIN STYLE -->
    <style>
        table, th, td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 1px;
        }
    </style>
    <!--  END STYLE -->

</head>
<body>
<h2>Current Dogs In Rescue</h2>
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Rescue Date</th>
        <th>Vaccinated</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr th:each="dogs : ${dogs}">
        <td th:text="${dogs.id}">Text ...</td>
        <td th:text="${dogs.name}">Text ...</td>
        <td th:text="${dogs.rescued}">Text ...</td>
        <td th:text="${dogs.vaccinated}">Text...</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>

<h2>Add A Dog</h2>
<form action="#" th:action="@{/}" method="post">
    <label>Name<input type="text" name="name" id="name"></input></label>
    <label>Vaccinated<input type="text" name="vaccinated" id="vaccinated"></input></label>
    <label>Rescued<input type="text" name="rescued" id="rescued"></input></label>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The html file is not fetching the information.
Kindly help me
Whole Project is available in 
https://github.com/arulsuju/DogRescue.git

Comment: add <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"> in your HTML

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the same variable name for iteration as the list variable (**dogs**)
, Consider using different name for iteration variable like (**dog**), so the code should be:

```
<tr th:each="dog : ${dogs}">
    <td th:text="${dog.id}">Text ...</td>
    <td th:text="${dog.name}">Text ...</td>
    <td th:text="${dog.rescued}">Text ...</td>
    <td th:text="${dog.vaccinated}">Text...</td>
</tr>
```